# Movie with college/high school guys, strippers and the strip club owner

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

I watched this movie years ago when I was a kid, and I don't remember its name but I remember that I loved it.

It is a 70s/80s American comedy movie about some guys in either high school or college (it reminds me of movies like Animal House or Revenge of The Nerds when I think of it). They have a virgin friend that apparently has an either really small or really big penis, and in the end of the movie he has sex with a brunette girl inside a school bus in a forest while everyone is waiting for them outside the bus, and he keeps going on the bus to get condoms because he never manages to find one that fits right.

Also, I remember that they go to a strip club, where the virgin guy pays to see the breasts of a stripper and another guy complains that the virgin guy is paying too much just for a tits flash. Then, they all end up having some problems with the owner of the strip club (as I recall, he is a fat old man that looks like Hitchcock and wears a hat and a white tuxedo), and one of the man's bodyguards beats one of the protagonists, so they decide to take revenge on the club owner and, I don't remember their plan or the whole scene, but I remember that they make the guy's limo falls off from a small bridge into a lake and that they communicate using bird sounds during the mission.

Also, I may be wrong, but I think that this movie is a sequel, because I think that there was a "2" by the end of its name.

Comment: Likely something in the [Porky's](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084522) series.

Comment: To me it sounds like porky's or porky's 2.

Comment: @dbugger I think you can put this up. Though I don't think the details are 100% accurate, I'm pretty sure this is *Porky's* too, esp. the bus scene.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Adding sources to the [OP's comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60723/movie-with-college-high-school-guys-strippers-and-the-strip-club-owner#comment96133_60723) and expanding answer.</sup>

The movie you are looking for is *[Porky's](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084522/)*. This is a 1981 Canadian-American sex comedy film.

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084522/),

> In 1954, **a group of Florida high schoolers seek out to help their buddy lose his virginity**, which leads them to seek revenge on a sleazy nightclub owner and his redneck sheriff brother for harassing them.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porky%27s#Plot) article of the page,

> They go to **Porky's, a nightclub out in the Everglades, believing that they can hire a prostitute to satisfy their sexual desires. Porky takes their money but humiliates the kids by dumping them in the swamp**. When the group demands their money back, the sheriff, who turns out to be Porky's brother, arrives to drive them away, but not before his minions extort the rest of their money and cause them more embarrassment.